# Python RE "re,findall"

Tags: python, regex

Thank you in advance. My question is:

I have a block of Python code in which I am attempting to use "os.walk,re and re.findall ip" in attempting to find all ip addresses within several files such as:

```
file1:192.168.3.1
file1:192.168.3.2
file1:mary had a little lamb
file1:192.168.3.3
file1:192.168.3.11
file1:10.255.3.1

file10:192.168.3.1
file10:192.168.3.2
file10:192.168.3.3
file10:192.168.3.4
file10:192.168.3.11
file10:192.168.1.1
file10:10.255.3.1

file2:192.168.3.1
file2:192.168.3.2
file2:192.168.3.3
file2:192.168.3.4
file2:192.168.3.11
file2:192.168.1.1
file2:10.255.3.1

file3:192.168.3.1
file3:192.168.3.2
file3:192.168.3.3
file3:192.168.3.4
file3:192.168.3.11
file3:192.168.1.1
file3:10.255.3.1
```

etc etc. My code block

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
  for file in files:
    matches = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", open(file, "r").read())
    if matches:
        print "Here is what is inside %s = %s" % (file,matches[0])
```

What happens is it only lists one particular type of ip such as:

```
Here is what is inside file3 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file6 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file7 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file1 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file9 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file5 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file8 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file10 = 192.168.3.1
Here is what is inside file4 = 192.168.3.1
```

In thinking that it was my regex was incorrect, I tested it with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

and the regular expression tested fine with my data that I supplied at the site in that it found everything that was an ip address. What am I doing wrong and why is re.findall not accepting my tested regex?

Answer (score 6):

You are only printing out one match:

```
if matches:
    print "Here is what is inside %s = %s" % (file,matches[0])
```

instead of all of them

```
if matches:
    for match in matches:
        print "Here is what is inside %s = %s" % (file,match)
```

Comment: brilliant, it had to be something so small to make me feel so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You are only printing the first match, and - at least for the part of the dataset you've shown - the *first* entry is always `192.168.3.1`.

Maybe you want to print all matches? You can do that with

```
print '\n'.join(matches)
```

Comment: awesome. The small details sometimes get the best of you

Answer (score 0):

could you be just matching the first line ? 
try adding /m flag to your regex

```
pattern = re.compile("whatever",re.MULTILINE)
```

also note that if you are matching a pattern with groups in it findall returns list of lists